# How to SELECT a postgresql tsrange column as json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to get a tsrange column returned as json but do not understand how get it to work in my query:

reserved is of type TSRANGE.
c.id and a.reservationid are of type TEXT.

```
-- query one
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, to_json(a.reserved) FROM complete_reservations c
JOIN availability a ON (c.id = a.reservationid)
```

throws

```
ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT c.*, to_json(a.reserved) FROM complete_reser...
                             ^
SQL state: 42883
Character: 22
```

it works if i try it like

```
-- query two
SELECT to_json('[2011-01-01,2011-03-01)'::tsrange);
```

Result:
`"[\"2011-01-01 00:00:00\",\"2011-03-01 00:00:00\")"`
and I do not understand the difference between both scenarios.

How do I get query one to behave like query two?

Comment: 1) I'm guessing it is in `ON (c.id = a.reservationid)`. What are the types for the fields on either side of the `=`? 2) Add the complete error message to the question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for the feedback. a.reserved is of type TSRANGE and reservation.id and c.id are both of type TEXT; I will update the question

Comment: there is no json type equivalent to tsrange, the json primitive types are string, number, boolean, null, object, array. The result of your query two is of json type string, is it really what you want / need ?

Comment:  uuuhh. of course. I did not at all consider the standards. I was simply expecting an array of strings, but @Edouard you make an excellent point! that might be for my use case correct but does not represent a tsrange and its capabilities at all!

I suppose the question then is rather: how can I construct a json array of strings from the two ends of a tsrange! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301709/how-to-select-a-postgresql-tsrange-column-as-json?noredirect=1#comment132875652_75301709) by Edouard, there seems to be no JSON representation of a tsrange. Therefore I framed my question wrong.

In my concrete case it was sufficent to turn the tsrange to an array of the upper() and lower() values of the TSRANGE and cast those values as strings. this way i can use the output as is and let my downstream tools handle them as json.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, ARRAY[to_char(lower(a.reserved),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),to_char(upper(a.reserved),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')] reserved FROM complete_reservations_with_itemidArray c
JOIN availability a ON (c.id = a.reservationid)
```

which returns a value like this in the reserved column: `{"2023-02-04 04:57:00","2023-02-05 04:57:00"}` which can be parsed as json if needed.

I post this for reference. I am not sure if it exactly answers my question as it was framed.

Comment: An array is not a range obviously. The information that is missing once the range has been "converted" into a json array is : are the lower and upper bounds included or excluded ? This may not be a blocking point when adopting the convention by default : lower bound included, upper bound excluded (or any other convention instead)